# How to use Celery with old/different Django project layout?

Tags: python, django, celery

My Django 1.6.5 project has the following layout:

```
project
├── reports
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── celery.py
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
```

The layout suggested by Django and Celery, looks like this:

```
project
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── celery.py
├── reports
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
├── manage.py
```

I've followed Celery's tutorial for Django project ( http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html ).

The problem is that when I try to run celery beat (from /home/project) with the following command:

```
celery -A project worker -B
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named project
```

This has worked for me with a test project using the suggested layout, but I cannot get it to work with this specific layout, which I cannot change by the way.

These are my files:

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os, sys
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**celery config @ settings.py:**

```
# Celery settings
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from datetime import timedelta

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=5))
def test_periodic_task():
    print 'Testing periodic task..'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder containing the `project` module is not in your system path. When running `celery.py`, the current working directory, `/path/to/project/` is added to the path, but you need to add the directory that's one level up, `/path/to/`, in order to import the `project` module:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__FILE__))
sys.path.prepend(BASE_DIR)
```

Comment: Hey. You mean celery.py the one that is in ~/repos/project, right? If so, I prepended that to my PATH variable from the command line before starting celery again. I'm still getting 'No module named project'. I double-checked PATH variable and it does contain the correct path to the file.

Comment: If you have `~/repos/project/__init__.py`, then `~/repos/` should be in your python path in order to import `project`. If that's not the issue, I'm not sure what is.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! I just accepted the answer. Is there anything else I can do to indicate that you helped me? I'm new here.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like I can only accept the answer. =)

Comment: When you get 15 reputation you can upvote answers, but for now accepting answers is all you can do. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use  `--workdir` in command something like

```
celery -A project worker -B --workdir /path/to/project
```

**Note**: project dir should have `__init__.py` file

Comment: Ah, man. Literally spent a day for finding this answer. Thank you!